# Alternative method for solving this equation involving a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the value of $c$ for which the series equals the indicated sum. 
$$ \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{cn} = 5$$

The $n=0$ made me think of geometric series.

So I solve it like this:

$r = e^{c}$ thus $ 5 = \frac{1}{1-e^{c}}$

resulting in $5e^c = 4$ which gives you $c = \ln \frac{4}{5}$

is this any alternative method for solving this?

Comment: That’s certainly how I’d solve it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott is it possible to solve in a different manner?

Comment: Probably, but I can’t think of another at the moment.

Comment: @GitGud I have tried putting the value of $c$ in to the sum on my calculator, but it doesn't compute a result.  So, I was asking if there was another method to check my results.

Comment: @MaoYiyi Are you looking to check if your solution is right or are you looking for alternative ways to solve this? In order to check if your value for $c$ satisfies the equality, note that $$e^{cn}=e^{nc}=e^{n\ln {4/5}}=e^{\ln {(4/5)^n}}$$ and recall that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions of each other.

Comment: @GitGud Both, more wanting to know alternative method, which would allow me to check my results.  Also, just wanted to know more about series.  If you know of alternative method to approach this problem, please post it.

Comment: @MaoYiyi I can't see any other way, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
5 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{cn} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{cn}
= 1 + e^{c}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{c(n-1)} = 1 + e^c \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{cn} = 1+5e^c
$$
so
$$
e^c = \frac{4}{5}
$$
and $c=\log(4/5)$.